# gitolite mirror error set access issues

Tags: git, gitolite

I am setting a git test repo via gitolite.

Don't understand what the issue here,
when trying to push

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: WARNING: subconf 'gitserver1' attempting to set access for repo1
remote: WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'repo1'
remote: WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'repo1'
remote: WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'repo1'
remote: WARNING: split conf not set, gl-conf present for 'repo1'
To git@10.50.2.221:gitolite-admin
   e79a565..a6aeecf  master -> master
Done
```

on gitolite logs I am getting:

```
 FATAL: W any gitolite-admin gitserver1 DENIED by fallthru
2016-01-27.12:44:56     12481           mirror: (or you mis-spelled the reponame)
2016-01-27.12:44:56     12481           mirror: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
2016-01-27.12:44:56     12410           system() failed,/home/git/bin/commands/mirror,push,gittrain3,gitolite-admin,-> 256
```

**EDIT**

running gitolite3 v3.1-8-ga509b20 on git 1.7.9.5

Comment: What version of gitolite are you using (as in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/AHA3pFeWHuI)

Comment: Not git, gitolite. Git 1.7.9.5 is very old, but the issue is with gitolite.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest gitolite? As I mentioned, this was fixed in 3.2.

Comment: thanks, mark you answer so I can vote, also can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041365/how-to-disconnect-gitolite-from-mirroring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/AHA3pFeWHuI) references the same error which could be fixed in gitolite 3.2 with [commit 16f2d9b](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/16f2d9b879516e6268fe8f12f930318f6916a42c)

> gl-conf must be created even if the repo para has only config lines
>   (i.e., no access rules but only config lines)

The first thing to do is to check if the issue persists when upgrading gitolite to its [latest version 3.6.4](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/releases) (3.1 is from October 2012).