# How to disconnect Gitolite from mirroring?

Tags: git, gitolite

Running Ubunutu and gitolite3 v3.6.4-19-g8de9b8d on git 1.7.9.5

I have configured 1 master and 2 slaves.
I am having issues with mirroring.

What I want to do is to stop the mirroring so I can push some configuration to `gitolite-admin` repo on the 2 slaves (I need to replace the pub keys).

However when I try to push to the slave I get error of:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
FATAL: server2: pushing 'gitolite-admin' to slave 'server2' not allowed
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Done
```

I guess this issue is because it is configured as slave, how can I stop the mirroring so I can push the configuration and than active it back again?

Comment: Do you see in the gitolite log something similar to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/Dj0Y5JokAzg?